# Why does returning false stop propagation with jQuery while it doesn't with POJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a jsfiddle using POJS showing that `return false;` doesn't stop the event's propagation: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/Lz2Pw/

Here is another using jQuery showing that `return false;` **does** stop the event's propagation: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/D5Mtg/

**Edit:** The one explaining to me why jQuery does this - differing from the original behavior intentionally - (and where in the code) gets the answer.

Here is the code (long, but very easy to read):

- HTML for both versions:

  ```
  <div id="parent1">
      <div id="child1"><a href="#" id="a1">child1</a></div>
  </div>

  <div id="parent2">
      <div id="child2"><a href="#" id="a2">child2</a></div>
  </div>

  <div id="parent3">
      <div id="child3"><a href="#" id="a3">child3</a></div>
  </div>
  ```
- POJS:

  ```
  document.getElementById( 'child1' ).onclick = function( e ) {
      console.log( 'child1' );
      e.preventDefault();
  };

  document.getElementById( 'parent1' ).onclick = function( e ) {
      console.log( 'parent1' );
  };

  document.getElementById( 'child2' ).onclick = function( e ) {
      console.log( 'child2' );
      return false;
  };

  document.getElementById( 'parent2' ).onclick = function( e ) {
      console.log( 'parent2' );
  };

  document.getElementById( 'child3' ).onclick = function( e ) {
      console.log( 'child3' );
      e.stopPropagation();
  };

  document.getElementById( 'parent3' ).onclick = function( e ) {
      console.log( 'parent3' );
  };
  ```
- jQuery version:

  ```
  $( '#child1' ).click( function( e ) {
      console.log( 'child1' );
      e.preventDefault();
  });

  $( '#parent1' ).click( function( e ) {
      console.log( 'parent1' );
  });

  $( '#child2' ).click( function( e ) {
      console.log( 'child2' );
      return false;
  });

  $( '#parent2' ).click( function( e ) {
      console.log( 'parent2' );
  });

  $( '#child3' ).click( function( e ) {
      console.log( 'child3' );
      e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $( '#parent3' ).click( function( e ) {
      console.log( 'parent3' );
  });
  ```

Comment: I wonder if the return false is being picked up by jQuery's event handling and stops the propagation there...

Comment: If that is so, I'd like to see where :-) Also, why would it be doing this?

Comment: Ah, this might be it. Go to the jQuery source (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js), search for 'event.stopPropagation', this happens just after a condition checking if a returned value is false.

Comment: Strange that `e.stopPropagation()` is the only method that works for your POJS example.

Comment: And from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (second to last paragraph under **The event handler and its environment**): "Returning `false` from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`."

Comment: @BenEverard I'd rather use http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/ to read jQuery source :-). Also, it's not strange, it's the normal behavior in POJS. jQuery doesn't follow it, and I have no idea why.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist heh, thanks. Why are they doing this?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I do too... however I couldn't seem to find the correct function to link to in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On line 3331 of [version 1.7.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js), in `jQuery.event.dispatch`:

```
ret = ( (jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler )
         .apply( matched.elem, args );

if ( ret !== undefined ) {
    event.result = ret;
    if ( ret === false ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

A lot of packaging has happened before this line, but basically, it runs the handler function (either a raw function, or the `handler` memeber function of a `handlerObject`) using `apply`.  If the result of that call is false, it does `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`.

This is mentioned in the documentation for [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Returning `false` from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`.

As for *why* they did it?  I don't know, as I'm not not the jQuery design team, but I assume it's just because `return false` is a lot quicker to type than `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();`.  (And if jQuery isn't about making sure you have less to type, I'm not sure what it's about.)

I don't believe the return value of an event handler is ever actually used *anywhere* in POJS (someone correct if that's wrong!).  Thus, jQuery can safely have a `return` statement cause side effects in a handler (since returning false in a POJS handler is meaningless, no POJS functionality is harmed).

Comment: Why does it do that? That's my main question (but +1 for showing exactly where in the code).

Comment: Heh, I guess I forgot the motto. Thanks!

Comment: Because usually people mean "throw away this event and do not do any further processing on it" when they `return false;` in the handler.

Comment: I added a bit of further elaboration that's a little bit speculative.  Let me know if I'm wrong about the return values of event handlers in POJS.

Comment: You are right on the first part of your post, but POJS does treat `return false` as `e.preventDefault()`, but only when used inside an `on*` handler. (And `return false`, even inside an `on*` handler, has no effect on stopping bubbling or capturing propagation, however.) See https://jsfiddle.net/5f1gmbjk/4/ for some examples.